# YAML file through http GET and gitlab api

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, yaml, gitlab

So I'm try to use the gitlab api to pull my CI job artifacts file. This is the URL:

```
https://WEBURL/api/v4/projects/923/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=Bundle Review
```

If I run it through the browser it immediately downloads the file and puts it into my downloads folder. Now I want to do this through a python script and parse the YAML for specific data.

```
artifactsURL = "https://WEBURL/api/v4/projects/" + str(projectID) + "/jobs/artifacts/master/download?job=Bundle Review"
header = {'PRIVATE-TOKEN': 'TOKENNUM'}
artifacts = requests.get(artifactsURL, headers=header)
print(artifacts.content)
```

And now I get this response:

```
PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00\x98%\x9cJ\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x18\x00fscm.ymlux\x0b\x00\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00UT\x05\x00\x01\xc1\xc8\x02Y\xecX\xdds\xe28\x12\x7f\xcf_\xa1\xb7T]\xc5\x1f|-DWT\x1d\x93\x90Ln3\x812$\xb7\xfb\xe4\x12rc4\xd8\x92K\x92I\xd8e\xff\xf7+\x7fb\xc0L\xc8&W\xb73wy\xa0"u\xb7\xba\xfb\xd7_\x929\xe8g!\x97\n\x9f!D\x05_\x81d\n\xa3\xdf\xff8Ch.\x05\xd7\xc5\xff1\xa7\x9a\t^\xd0\x94\x96@B\xc6\xfd|\xad%\x819[\xba2T\x86\x07\xab\xe44\x84\xe0E\x83\xe4$\xc0H\xcb\x18\xce\x14\xc8\x15\xa3\x90\xaa"\x113$\x10/c\xf4 \x02\xee)W\xf0lm\x94\xa6\x18\xde,\xdda!\xf1\x01#O\xd0%H3\xa6$\xf0\x89\\\x9b\x94X\x89F\xc6\xb5U\x9e\x18\x12\xa5A\xa6RU\xe7\x92\xbf\xad\x83<\x0e\x82\xc4c\xdf\xc8<\xc98\xa8\x08C\xc2\xbd\xc2\x08\xc3\xf0\xa5\x88\xa3\xc2\xa4\x82\xb7X/\x04\xa3P\xe5\xa8\x90=\x88\x02\xb1.\xf4JP"\x96\xb9\xeb\xe5\x16\xc8\x15\xc90-w\x11\n!\x14r\x8dQ\xc3\xb6\xbfl\xa55\x91\xda\x8dD\xc0\xe8z\xcbL\x05\xf7Xr\x00F\x82\x1bs\xc2\x82XBI\xf5  k\x8c\x9a\xb6:\x01@\xe5EV\ty\x8e\xc87p\xacD?\x07\xb2\xb4r\xcf\x96\x12\xf1\x13\xe3\xfcn\xdc\x9a\x9d\x028\xe0+&\x05\x0f\x81\xeb\x82\xf1j\xf4\xf04t\xee&\xee\xe7\xd1d\x8a\xd1\\\xd1\xd0\xc8\xdc4\xf3\xc4\xad"S\x089\x837\xf1\xdf\xde\xb8W\xcep0\x1d\xba\xff|\xfa\xe2\x8e\xc6\xd3\xbb\xd1\xc3\x04#\xe3:V M\xcdB\xf8Mp\xe8\x0fB\x90\x8c\x12k\xe8\x85\x82k\xc1_\x89\x92\x96e\x80p\xc7l\xd8f\xeb\xb4\x0cO\xfe\xf2B.r~\x0b9\xfe\x18\xcc?\x1e\xf2B\xe8q|\xeb\x0c\xae\x87\xee\xf5`:\xf84\x98\x0c\'\x18\x9d7\xce\xffT`\xbeY\x00V\x05\x14\x83\n>g\xbez[#)\xe4\x9f\xa1\x16\xd5\x80\xcc \xa8\x80\x97\xf7K37\'?\x1f\xef\xf7\xd1\x03\xfe4\x94\xc0=\x13\xb8\x96\xeb\xb1`\\+\x8c\x16ZG\x17\xc9\x8f:. \xe3\x000\xfa,\x94\xc6\xaf\xc0\xf5\xf71\xd1\x8b\xb1\x849{\xc1%0\x07\x07G")\xf6\xf3v\xbbu~H\x93B\x0b*\x82\xcc\xb2CYM|\x85Q\xd5\xc7\xba\xcc\x19L\xdc\xfb\xd1\xed\xdd\x83\xfb\xe8\xdc\xe7\'a\xcb\xa2D\xedD\x8f\x12e\x05\xc2g\xbc"\xf64\xb8\xbf\xbbN*\xf0U\xc9\x982/\x9fKO$`\x1e\xd1\xf0\xae\xc4\xfd\xa0\x94\xacT{\x9aQ\r\xb3a6j3q\xb7\xb6+ \x97\xa3\xb8\xa0y3\xc3#\x9a\x18\xf0\x92\x84\x0e\xe4\x91\xe2\x7f\xff\xa8\xa9\x89\xe5\xa7\xd1tz?\xbcv\xff5\x98\x0e\x1dw\xf4\xe0\x0e\x1dg\xe4`\x04/L\xd7\xb38\xd7C\xc7\xfd\xf4+F\x89\xcdb\xf6\x15\xa8V}\xe6]$K\xe0\x9a\xe9u\xb2\n\x18_nWDk\xc9f\xb1\x86\x15\tbP\xee\x8cq"\xd7}\xf1\xccA\xd6\x91\x85\x08\x8e\x12\xa9\xbf:JK\xb2\xe4(\x91\xc7\xe1Q\x9a\xd2\xf2\xb85\x7fac\xebC\xf48\x1d?N\xdd\x9b\x91\xf3e0\xc5\xe8\xab\x12\xbc\x96o<\x9aLo\x9d\xa4u/\x84\xd2\xfdJ\xa7EI"\xf6;\xedV\x13y3NB(\x89(\x99\x95\xfdH(\xedKP\xb5\xc7N\xae>\x0f\xbf\x0c&\x18E\xf1,`\xb4\x9e\xe7~4\xcd2\x08^\xa2Z\x8e\xe9\xe0\xd3}bZ%\xcb6\xdb\x14\xdbl\xf3k\xb3\x0f\xcf\xdf\xea\xcf\x1b\x8d\xef\xae\xdc\xab\xd1\xc3\xcd\xdd-F!(E|H\x87\xbe\x88\xb5\x19\xaa~\xdb\xb6\xedoH\x8e\x9d\xe1\xcd\xdd/\xb8\x9c\'\xbb\xd7\xdf\xa2EX3\xa1u\x00\xde3I\xea8 \x1a\x94\xae\xed\x0e\xb5\xd7\x81\xd3oo\xde\xcc\x10z\x01\xf2{\xeb\x193\xa2 \x14\x1e\x04YHw\xfb\x86^G\xb0\xdb;\x8a\x9d2\xc4\x1e\xcc\x19Om\xcf*\xe0\xa2r\xd7O\x18+\xcb4\x1b\xfa\x95\x8d\x0b\xb5V\x1aB*\xb8\xd2\x84\xa7\xba\xd3\xe1\xdfO\x7f\x97\xb0\xbe\xd0\x10FI\xcc\xfa\xdf{a\xa5\xb9\xf1Ze\xed\xc5b\xb3\x1b\x88\xcdn\x1465!\xd8T\xc0\xdd\xec#\xbf\xd9E{\x93\x82\xbc)\x10\xfe_(\xd1\xf0\xf4\x17l\xc9[\xac\x89&ih\xf2\xf5\xff\xdf\xaf\x87\xf0\x8a7\xc0+\x0e\xe1\xcd\x92\xfe?\x83\xef\x0f\x01\xb0O4<\x93\xf5\xf7\xfef:8#\x7f\x1e\xf5\xec\x9e\xfd\xda\xfb\xe8\x80|\xf8<B(\n\x08\x85\xeaxL\xc3\xab\xb4$\xa9;\xe5\xa6\x81\xb8\xf0\xc0\x94"\x00\xd4\xef\xa3\x90p\xe2\xe7A\xca#\\~\xca\xb3\n\xecm\xb3s\xe4sB\xe5\xb3\xdf\t/\x0c\x84V"\x88\xc3"\x8d\rd\xad\x88\xb4d\xcc\xad<dJ\xd0%\xae\xdd\x94\xcfg\x08-\xc9|I\xcaL\xd8\xfbR\xf4\x9b\x10K\x80(\xf7%\x99x\xc9`\xc3\x99P\xd5\xbf\xb2\x03g\xc7\xd9f\xc36\x9b\xa6}b\x9e\xa6BF\x92\xab\xc7\x0c\xd9*|\xc5\xa8\xf4\x94\xe3\x96eJZo\xb6M\x8b\x88Qe\xc4,c\xac\xb99\xfd<\xb8\xf9y\xe0:\xc3\xc9\xd4\x1d;\xa3_~\xdd>\x83\xb1U\xd5\xdd\xb3{\xcd\\$\xe5\xc3\xe8\\\xcb\x18\xce\xab6\x07\x84{BD\xd6\xben\xdb\xec\x1d\xc9\x99\xba\xdaO\xaa\xa1\xcc\x8a\x9em\xdb8\xf9\xb14M\x92?\\&\xc5\x15I\xf1\xf5\xa8G\xf3H\n\nJ\xe1\ns\xd5\xca#_u\xb6\xa9\x9e\x08\xfdC-H\xb3\xf3\x13\xee\xc2\x1c\xbav\xab\xd7\xe8^6\x1a\x97\xbd\xb9\xddiwH\xc7\x86K\xf0\x1av\xe7\'\xe2u\xbd\xe6\xac=\xef\xb6/\xbb\x94\x92\xf9\xcc\xbb\xecv\x1aM\xb8l\xb4\xe6\xed\x86\xd7\xcd\xbc\xdemN\x85\xa2\x1d\x04O\x9a\xf4\x87\x15\x16.#\xea\x03\x07I\x82\x93\xf0(\xb9\x7fT@\x92`\x03\xd5\x86\x96\xcc\xf7A\xaa\xdaQ\xbc\xcf\xf4\xdf\x05\xe3\xb4>zX)\x912\xa8\x08\x02\xa0Z\xc8Z7sj\xba\xfa\x0bO\xcbH\xa95\xa7\xaf~\\\xcc\xd8\x0eN,g\xa7\xfd\x11\xb3s\xbf\xf9F\x7f\xf6\x02s|\xf0E\xcaH\x1fKj\x01\xf5a\xcb\xa9\x1fi\x8f\xa2\x0b\x08\x93F\xee3\xa5\xe5\xfa=\xd3j\xef\xa8Z+\xf7\xd5\xbden\x95z\xf1\x9e\xe2]\x83r\x95[\xee\x96\xd96\x1b\xa7)Y\x81TY\xbbi\x99\xf6\xf9Yq\x0fA\xbf\xffqv\xf6\xef\x00\x00\x00\xff\xffPK\x07\x08\xd7\x9aY\xef \x06\x00\x00\xe3\x1c\x00\x00PK\x01\x02\x14\x03\x14\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00\x98%\x9cJ\xd7\x9aY\xef \x06\x00\x00\xe3\x1c\x00\x00\x08\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa4\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00fscm.ymlux\x0b\x00\x01\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00UT\x05\x00\x01\xc1\xc8\x02YPK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00N\x00\x00\x00n\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

Which seems to be a bunch of binary but I don't know what to do to read it. I want to be able to use PYYAML and load the YAML

```
print(yaml.load(artifacts.content))
```

Comment: could you try `print(artifacts.json)`

Comment: <bound method Response.json of <Response [200]>>

Comment: sorry `print(artifacts.json())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading artifacts from GitLab gives you a .zip file - See the notes at the start of https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html where it says:

```
Starting with GitLab 8.4 and GitLab Runner 1.0, the artifacts archive format 
changed to ZIP, and it is now possible to browse its contents, with the added 
ability of downloading the files separately.
```

The start of your data is `PK` which confirms this. If your browser is not giving you a zip file it might be uncompressing the download for you.

There's a [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html%20zipfile) module, and to use it with a bytestring in python3, you'll need to use the `io` module, too:

```
import io
import zipfile

# construct artifactsURL and header as you were
artifacts = requests.get(artifactsURL, headers=header)

zip_fh = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(artifacts.content))
```

And then use either the `extract` or `extractall` methods in the `zipfile` module to get the data you need from the file archive.

If you'd like to download a specific file, then https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#downloading-the-latest-job-artifacts also has notes about that, including how to build the URL for that specific file.